# How to prepend text to this img src using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src, prepend

So basically I have this code and need to prepend some text to the src value.

```
<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" alt="Foto" border="0"/></img>
```

Can I use JQuery to change the src value to

```
src="/b2b/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="
```

Thanks

Comment: Query the image from the DOM, then use `attr()` to change the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img[src^="/servlet/servlet"]').attr('src', function(_,src) {
    return '/b2b' + src;
});
```

and image tags are self closing, so you should remove `</img>`

Comment: I'm interested, what exactly does the underscore param do in your attr callback?

Comment: @wvandaal - It does .... wait for it .... nothing. It's a common way to indicate that the argument is not being used, but still needs to be there to access the second argument